# Path relative to include in ant

Tags: ant

I have an ant build system.  I have some common build files (common.xml) that other build files (such as foo) import.  Often times, I would like to include/refer to a file from the common build file.  However, these paths end up being relative to project foo's build.xml.

Is it possible to have foo's build.xml import common.xml (which is in ../) but still have common.xml refer to files in common.xml's directory?

In other words, in common.xml I want to write paths relative to common.xml's directory, not foo's directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the section "Resolving files against the imported file" in the [`import` task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html).

Basically you need to get the path of the common.xml file using the `dirname` task, and use this to construct the path to the relative file.